# Scale mode window on same workspace?

Tags: unity, 12.04

I have recently upgraded from ubuntu 11.10 to ubuntu 12.04. Generally in unity if we open several interface of an application then we can switch them by double clicking the icon of the application on unity panel. It shows the opened application's multiple interface in scale mode.

But ubuntu 12.04 does not show the windows of different workspace in scale mode. If i open three nautilus, two in same and one in different workspace then click on icon show two interface (which workspace contains two). That's means it only shows current workspace's application's interface.

Is it a bug or feature of ubuntu 12.04? Is there any way to fix it?

Comment: There is a bug report for 12.04 at (https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/compiz/+bug/933776). Another issue is that the ability to assign a window edge for the window picker and workspace picker does not hold between boots and must be reset each boot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The picking from all workspaces when left clicking on launcher icon was intentionally removed. Actually the process to do so began early in Natty dev, just took a while but was inevitable

Bug report that started it - https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/689733

Additionally one cannot directly set a binding for it in scale, initiate_all from all WS's was also intentionally removed in the scale plugin source starting in compiz-0.9.4

It is however possible to patch scale.cpp, rebuild the plugin & get `window picker for window group` from all Ws's thru a command, dbus & keyboard combo, do so here & it works just fine.

Method to patch & enable will be maintained thru 12.04 release in this thread concerning a cuberotate hack, if interested read post 1 & 15, ask there if need be - http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1938942

Otherwise you can use the Alt-Tab switcher & disabling  the `bias alt-tab to prefer windows on the current viewport` option in the unity plugin settings to get from all WS's

Answer (score 1):

I was the guy who wrote the post saying [compile yourself is NOT the answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126867/show-windows-on-all-workspaces-scale-addon-not-working).

I still think the same: **compile it yourself is not the Ubuntu's way** (may be true for CentOS, Slackware or other linux distros).

Fortunately, **there is a solution**: someone skilled did for us (not an Ubuntu developer, sadly). Here is a PPA where you can download the uncrippled version of Compiz that can show windows from all workspaces:

https://launchpad.net/~bsantos/+archive/ppa

I'm using it and so far it works fine.

Thanks very much **Bruno Santos**!

I found this solution buried deep in this thread:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/compiz/+bug/933776