# Show windows on all workspaces? (scale addon not working)

Tags: unity, 12.04, compiz, application-switcher, scale-mode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Scale mode window on same workspace?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/115209/scale-mode-window-on-same-workspace)

Is there a way to show windows on ALL WORKSPACES? I can use alt+tab, after changing behaviour through ccsm, but Unity switcher only shows icons, which is very ugly and old-fashioned. Showing windows is far more convenient, and very common in modern workspaces, like mac and other linux's window managers.

I've found [a solution, wich involves recompiling compiz](https://askubuntu.com/questions/115209/scale-mode-window-on-same-workspace)!!

Seriously?? It sounds like *old days: compile it yourself*!. I though Ubuntu was different...

Removing features from source code is not the way I think. What about flexibility and freedom of choice? Without a a way to see windows in all workspaces you just have to remember in which workspace is the window you are looking for, and the default switcher does not show windows, only generic (and confusing) icons. Even in windows 7 I can see windows previews to select between different windows of the same program (file explorer, for example).

[Other solution propposed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/125733/show-all-windows-in-12-04) uses the shift switcher, but it doesn't work very well and is not as good (by far) as scale showing the windows. By the way, all compiz switchers I know are far less useful than scale.

Is there a way to revert back all scale functionality? (no recompiling, please). If a developer could compile an uncrippled version of scale and make a downloable deb package?

Thanks very much and sorry for my english, is not my native language.

Comment: I think this question is more detailed and clear than the possible duplicate.